# Remove all the strings before and after a certain word in bash

Tags: shell, grep, ping

I am using `ping` to check the connectivity of a network.

What I want is the number of received packets only.

For example if `ping -c10 -q 8.8.8.8 | grep received` output is:

```
10 packets transmitted, 5 received, 50% packet loss, time 9016ms
```

I only want to see number 5 in output and nothing before or after it.

So expected output is: `5`

Comment: If it's for some sort of monitoring, note that there's a nagios / icinga plugin that can run `ping` and parse its output for you. Like `check_ping -H 8.8.8.8 -p 10  -w 500,50% -c 2000,80%` to report "warning" if there's a rtt > 500ms or over 50% packet loss, and critical if rtt > 2s and packet loss over 80%

Comment: Edit the question and add the expected output so that what you are looking for is known for sure.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas. Thanks. It sounds interesting I will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `grep` with `-P` option :

```
grep -Po '\d+(?= received)'
```

You can also do using `awk` :

```
awk '$5 == "received,"{print $4}'
```

Comment: Thanks. grep with -oP switch worked as expected.